# Tried to install lamp-server on Ubuntu 10.10 (weird error)

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

Ran the following command from a user account listed with ALL permissions in visudo.

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
tasksel: aptitude failed (100)
```

Any idea what this is/what caused it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have just installed tasksell, then rebooting may help you.